# Weird behaviour with nested multicol environments

Tags: itemize, multicol

I wanted to use the multicols environment to make a multicolumn itemize environment. The problem is I'm already using the multicols* environment in my main document and nesting them seems to break things when a page break occurs at a very specific place. I had trouble to replicate it (it looks unstable) but here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\lipsum[1-8]

Test

Test

Test

Test

Test

Test

Test

Test

Test

\begin{enumerate}
\item First question
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\item Second question
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Here is the compiled pdf (using pdflatex or lualatex): [image]

The columns in the first page seem to align with the ones in the itemize environment.

Any help to understand what happens here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice example:-) You could raise an issue at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues but a quick workaround is to box and unbox the inner list

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\lipsum[1-8]

Test

Test

Test

Test

Test

Test

Test

Test

Test

\begin{enumerate}
\item First question

\setbox0\vbox{
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
}\unvbox0

\item Second question
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this works, thanks! I raised an issue because i don't see a reason why my version shouldn't work.

Comment: It is now fixed in the develop branch and will show up in the next pdflatex-dev and then finally in the June release